# How can I save a "setting" in a C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, variables

A user wants me to create an app that does something everything he presses the X key.

Now he asked me to make it so he can change what key he has to press. Maybe he wants X key today, maybe C key tomorrow.

How can I easily do this in C#? What is the best way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use .Net's [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx) feature.

Go to the Settings tab in Project Properties and add a setting.
You can then access it in code  by writing `Properties.Settings.Default.MySettingName`.

Comment: sounds cool, where does it save the setting? in the .exe? or registry?

Comment: I'm trying to access my propety but all I see in the intellisense is: Default, Equals, Reference Equals. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Sergio: I forgot to mention that you need to add `.Default.`; I fixed the answer.

Comment: It saves it to an XML file, usually the name of your app.exe.config. You reference it using Settings.Default.MySettingName. The problem is, I don't think you can write to it using the Settings class. I don't think it preserves the changes you make to it in code....

Comment: OK, I just double checked. After you make a change, be sure to call Settings.Default.Save();